# Watson Assistant (Conversation) service behaves differently when created via API versus created in the Browser

Tags: watson-conversation

We are seeing different behaviour when we create a workspace in the WebInterface versus when we create the same conversation via the API.

The JSON export for the dialognode is the same:

> {         "type": "standard",
>       "title": "SmallTalk: weerbericht",
>         "output": {
>   "text": {
>                 "values": [],
>                 "selection_policy": "sequential"            }       },
>   "parent": "smalltalk_container",
>
> "context": {           "user_weer": "@weerbericht",
>             "user_location": "@plaatsnamen"         },
>   "metadata": {
>             "_customization": {
>                 "mcr": false            }       },
>       "next_step": {          "behavior": "jump_to",          "selector": "condition",            "dialog_node": "node_33_1519129633532"
>         },
>   "conditions": "#ST_weersbericht",
>       "description": null,
>         "dialog_node": "node_9_1517408489377",
>         "previous_sibling": "node_3_1518680265483"  },

But the behaviour is different, which can be explained when we look at the UI
there is a difference
This is the UI for the dialogNode created via the browser
[image]

This is the UI for the same dialogNode created via the API
[image]

One difference we found is the Multiple Reponse switch:
[image]
It should be OFF (image on the right) and as per the JSON (mcr:false).
But even when we switch it on manually, the context variables don't show.

What should I be looking for in the API to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

The dialog model for multiple condition responses is that the parent node needs to be either standard dialog node or frame. Now when adding a multiple condition response to this node (and hence making an MCR node out of that parent node) you need to add a dialog node with `"type":"response_condition"` under this node.

This is a way how to create multiple condition responses through the api.

To give you and example to create MCR node:
[image]

The JSON of dialog nodes that need to pushed through the API will look like:

```
{
    "type": "standard",
    "title": "mcr node",
    "output": {

    },
    "parent": null,
    "context": null,
    "metadata": {
        "_customization": {
            "mcr": true
        }
    },
    "next_step": null,
    "conditions": "#book_flight",
    "digress_in": "does_not_return",
    "description": null,
    "dialog_node": "node_8_1525086089064",
    "digress_out": "allow_all",
    "previous_sibling": null
},
{
    "type": "response_condition",
    "title": null,
    "output": {
        "text": {
            "values": ["I see city entity!"]
        }
    },
    "parent": "node_8_1525086089064",
    "context": null,
    "metadata": {

    },
    "next_step": null,
    "conditions": "@city",
    "description": null,
    "dialog_node": "node_9_1525086100114",
    "previous_sibling": null
},
{
    "type": "response_condition",
    "title": null,
    "output": {
        "text": {
            "values": ["I don't see anything."]
        }
    },
    "parent": "node_8_1525086089064",
    "context": null,
    "metadata": {

    },
    "next_step": null,
    "conditions": "anything_else",
    "description": null,
    "dialog_node": "node_10_1525086122332",
    "previous_sibling": "node_9_1525086100114"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip, I need some time to verify this in our environment